# Error 1045 Lost Access to phpmyadmin after reboot

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just hard rebooted my server for the first time within 7 months. So basically what happened is, I can't login to phpmyadmin anymore.

Everything worked fine but now when I try to access it with my root credentials I get: #1045 Not possible to login in the mySQL server

I have a password currently set in the config.inc.php and it's permissions are 644. Running on CentOS.

Config: http://pastebin.com/4envkWRw

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you able to connect in via command line? mysql -u root -pPassword ?

Comment: No, I get 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
I tried to check databases, and all db's are gone.

Comment: I would reset the MySQL password. It seems like an odd one - possibly corrupted file from unexpected shutdown? Maybe check the logs to be sure. I don't think I can help too much with this one.
 
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password

Comment: Oh damn, you gotta love stack overflow community! You just saved me from a night trying to search for solutions. Thank you! Problem is solved.